# Why does ip address have a dash

Tags: ip, ip-address

Why does my ip address have a dash at the end of it?  It was assigned to me by AT&T Uverse.

106.206.186.224-8

Comment: ask at&t Uverse.

Comment: While I can understand why people are downvoting this, it's entirely within the realm of possibility that a provider would take a standard address and morph it into a nonstandard entity for the purpose of account or configuration management. If you look at your AT&T phone bill, your account number is probably a morphed version of your phone number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no, they dont. possibly it's a way of indicating address range 224 to 228 [although not very professional - i would rather expect [CIDR notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation)].

Comment: I don't think you can represent the IP range .224 through .228 using CIDR. /29, /30 and /31 do not match .224 though .228 .

Comment: @StefanLasiewski that's valid point; still ranges - especially expressed in ambiguous way are are not very precise way of communicating.

Answer (score 2):

You have been assigned addresses 224 through 228 - 224,225,226,227, and 228.