# Non-standard IP address with dashes

Tags: ip, ip-address, netbsd

I ran the `who` command on a shared NetBSD box, and this weird user IP came up:

```
<redacted> pts/33   May 13 02:13  (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)
<redacted> pts/35   May 12 20:59  (202-172-110-147-)
<redacted> pts/36   May  6 20:36  (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)
```

I've never seen an IP like that. Obviously, `ping 202-172-110-147-` will complain with "Cannot resolve ... (Unknown host)".

There was a similar question [posted 7 years ago](https://serverfault.com/q/392803/574541), which posited that it was a non-standard way of denoting IP ranges, but seeing there's a `-` at the end of the address, it doesn't seem like a similar thing.

---

Edit:

I've tried reverse DNS with `nslookup 202-172-110-147-`, which errors with "** server can't find 202-172-110-147-: NXDOMAIN"

Doing `w <user>` returns:

```
9:49AM  up 89 days,  7:46, 1 user, load averages: 0.23, 0.18, 0.17
USER          TTY     FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
<redacted>    pts/35  202-172-110-147- Tue08PM  4:13
```

Edit 2: This is on NetBSD, not Linux like I mentioned at the beginning (I thought the box was Linux):

```
$ uname -rsv
NetBSD 8.1 NetBSD 8.1 (GENERIC) #0: Fri May 31 08:43:59 UTC 2019  mkrepro@mkrepro.NetBSD.org:/usr/src/sys/arch/amd64/compile/GENERIC
```

Edit 3: Following @NStorm update, I ran `w -n` to display network addresses as numbers. I still see the same result

```
$ w -n <user>
 9:57AM  up 89 days,  7:54, 1 user, load averages: 0.12, 0.12, 0.14
USER          TTY     FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
<redacted>    pts/35  202-172-110-147- Tue08PM  4:22
```

Comment: Are you sure you see an IP-Address and not a name? Reverse DNS may map this to the IP address and the rules there are different.

Comment: The [linked question](https://serverfault.com/q/392803/574541) would seem to be referring to something quite different.

Comment: You can't just always nslookup back to get IP from RR. They don't always map to each other. You can simply specify non-existing domain in the RR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just a DNS RR (reverse record) resolved from IP to that name.

There is no way to really map resolved RR back to original IP as the records are independent. Moreover the RR can contain non-existing domain name. So you can't rely on RR to obtain information on the logged on users IP.

To check back real IP without DNS resolution, you can use `last -a -i` command which not only shows currently logged in users but also all recent logins.

If you really need to show only currently logged users, you can simply filter last output with grep like this: `last -ai | grep "still logged in"`

Or you can simply use `w -fi` as per Janne Pikkarainen comment below, if you have modern distro. I've just realized that it is really unsupported distro versions already which lack the support for -i key of this tool, like CentOS 5. Just keep in mind - if your distro complains on `w -fi`, you can always use `last` command as noted above.

EDIT: As OP update information on the OS below (NetBSD 8.1) here is the way to get IP instead of DNS records on NetBSD according to the [NetBSD man pages](https://man.netbsd.org/w.1): `w -n`

```
    -n      Show network addresses as numbers (normally w interprets
                 addresses and attempts to display them symbolically).
```

Or `last -n -f /var/run/utmptx`:

```
     -n             Print host addresses numerically.  This option works only
                    on wtmpx(5) entries, and prints nothing on wtmp(5)
                    entries.
```

[According to the NetBSD manpages](https://man.netbsd.org/getutxent.3), if the user is currently logged `/var/run/utmptx` is the only place where it logs real IP of the currently logged in users as `struct sockaddr_storage ut_ss` field. If you don't have access to that file and/or current network connections (`netstat` for example, which you most likely don't have access too) you can't tell for sure. The best way is to guess then.

It seems like the `202-172-110-147-` record is truncated from the FQDN. But we can try guessing it belongs the IP `202.172.110.147` which was try digging RR. And bingo:

```
dig -x 202.172.110.147
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
147.110.172.202.in-addr.arpa. 300 IN    PTR     202-172-110-147-cpe.spintel.net.au.
```

Seems like this is the one. And the full hostname is `202-172-110-147-cpe.spintel.net.au` which is just truncated in `who` and other tool output.

If you have access to the `/var/log/wtmpx` you can get that IP from there but only once this user will log out.

Comment: Or just with `w -fi` to get the currently logged in users, and to show their IP addresses.

Comment: @JannePikkarainen yes, if you have modern w. Older versions of w didn't had -i key. That is why I've stick with last as more universal solution.

Comment: I don't have an `-i` option on `w` or `last`. This particular user didn't show up after doing `last`, and `w` still shows the original "202-172-110-147-" in the `FROM` field.

Comment: @ergl what OS & version are you running?

Comment: Apparently it's NetBSD 8.1 (I though this was Linux, I'll edit the question tags)

Comment: @ergl I've updated my answer to reflect NetBSD way to get IPs.

Comment: Thanks for the update, although I still see the same IP. I've edited the question,

Comment: @ergl Did you tried `w -n` and `last -n`?

Comment: Yes, `last -n` doesn't show this particular user

Comment: @ergl please try `last -n -f /var/run/utmpx` and `last -n -f /var/log/wtmpx`. I don't have NetBSD installed at hand to try it myself right now.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have privileges to check `/var/run/utmpx`. With `last -n -f /var/log/wtmp`, I still don't this particular user.

Comment: @ergl note the x at the end of the file name. This is an eXtended log which is supposed to store original IP along with hostname.

Comment: Yes, sorry, `last -n -f /var/log/wtmpx` still doesn't show this user (which is weird, because I can still see the user with `who`, but `last` doesn't list it as "still logged in").

Comment: @ergl seems like `/var/run/utmpx` is the only place. I've updated my answer with more details on this.

Comment: Nice! I have access to `netstat` (surprisingly), and it lists `202-172-110-147-.XXXX` as a telnet connection. Mystery solved.